# How would I compute the loss of a network, when a certain output is not exactly known

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network

I am building a physics informed neural network whose total loss depends on a few individual loss terms, which must each be minimised. The output of the network is not known, and that is why I rely solely on minimising the residual from the differential equations and the initial/boundary conditions. The problem I am having is that there is one condition where I do not have an exact answer I am looking for, rather I know exactly what I am NOT looking for.

I have two tensors filled with floats that are pretty much zero. However, during training I would like the network to look for a solution in which these tensors do NOT have zeros. The way I went about it was:

```
    sampled_df_dr = # A tensor with the floats
    sampled_dg_dr = # The other tensor with the floats

    # Tensor with zeros, same size as the sample
    df_dr_flags = torch.zeros_like(sampled_df_dr)
    dg_dr_flags = torch.zeros_like(sampled_dg_dr)

    m = 0

    for dfdr, dgdr in zip(sampled_df_dr, sampled_dg_dr):
        
        if dfdr.item() > upper_zero_bound or dfdr.item() < lower_zero_bound:
            # Set that element to "1" to flag that it is NOT a zero
            df_dr_flags[m] = 1
        
        if dgdr.item() > upper_zero_bound or dfdr.item() < lower_zero_bound:
            dg_dr_flags[m] = 1

    df_dr_target = torch.ones_like(df_dr_flags)
    dg_dr_target = torch.ones_like(dg_dr_flags)

    # loss_function here is the MSE
    derivative_constraint_f = loss_function(df_dr_flags, df_dr_target)
    derivative_constraint_g = loss_function(dg_dr_flags, dg_dr_target)
```

So in the end I hoped that the network would see my need for more non-zero flags and therefore produce more non-zero values. But I guess during backprop, the actual tensors with floats don't get improved. Any ideas how I might go about this?

Comment: I didnt dig into your code, but you could minimize `- tensor_to_grow.sum()`, no? This would encourage to put as large values into `tensor_to_grow` as possible. You would probably need some rules to limit excessiv growth. Maybe you know that the sum of all values should be close to a target sum? minimize `mse(tensor_to_grow.sum(), target_sum)`.